# Autofac registered AuthorizationFilter calling twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

Hi I have an Authorization filter, created using Autofac support for WebApi. Summary as follows:

```
public class ApplicationTokenValidatorAttribute : IAutofacAuthorizationFilter
{
    //...

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor for ApplicationTokenValidatorAttribute
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tenancyClient">Tenancy service used to resolve application key checks and populate tenancy object on valid controllers</param>
    /// <param name="commonServices">Provides access to commonly used services, including logging and performance tracing</param>
    public ApplicationTokenValidatorAttribute(ITenancyClient tenancyClient, ICommonServices commonServices)
    {
        _tenancyClient = tenancyClient;
        _commonServices = commonServices;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pass/fails authentication, based on whether you provide a valid application key in the http headers of the request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionContext">Action filter context</param>
    public void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //...
    }
```

I don't believe the actual code in the filter is important, but if anyone thinks otherwise, then I can sanity check it and paste more.

I register it using this autofac code

```
builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
builder.Register(c => 
    new ApplicationTokenValidatorAttribute(
            c.Resolve<ITenancyClient>(),
            c.Resolve<ICommonServices>()))
        .AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterFor<TenantAwareApiController>()
        .InstancePerApiRequest();
```

which is I think as laid out in https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WebApiIntegration.

If I do it like this however, it is called twice for every request.

If I comment out the line

`builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);`

then the filter is only called once, as expected. Can anyone shed some light on this? DO I need this line? I'm loath to exclude the statement specifically listed in the documentation, but it seems to be the source of the issue.

cheers,

P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

will register anything that implements the `IAutofacAuthorizationFilter` interface. So strictly speaking, you shouldn't need the second line.

The second line just re-registers what Autofac is already automatically doing in  the line above. So, remove the second line.

Comment: great thanks - that was not so clear from the docs. Though I only want this to fire on particular controller types, so perhaps I do want the second line and not the first?

Comment: Perhaps, the first line is very much a 'catch all', so you can have all your attributes implementing the same interface. If you ant more control, use the second line, but also read further into the documentation as it does provide some useful alternatives.